# Faster way to convert a list to a data.frame with some column values missing

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have this list of list

```
> head(train)
[[1]]
[[1]]$Physics
[1] 8

[[1]]$Chemistry
[1] 7

[[1]]$PhysicalEducation
[1] 3

[[1]]$English
[1] 4

[[1]]$Mathematics
[1] 6

[[1]]$serial
[1] 195490

.
.
[[6]]
[[6]]$Physics
[1] 2

[[6]]$Chemistry
[1] 1

[[6]]$Biology
[1] 2

[[6]]$English
[1] 4

[[6]]$Mathematics
[1] 8

[[6]]$serial
[1] 182318
```

each sub-list has any five elements out of these 12 and one extra named `serial`

```
columns <- c("Physics", "Chemistry", "PhysicalEducation", "English", 
             "Mathematics", "serial", "ComputerScience", "Hindi", "Biology", 
             "Economics", "Accountancy", "BusinessStudies")
```

I am trying yo convert this list into data frame.

Presently, I am doing this using this for loop by iterating one row at a time. Although this works, it takes a huge amount of time.

```
colclass <- rep("numeric",12)
comby <- read.table(text = '', colClasses = colclass, col.names = columns)  
for(i in 1:length(train)){
    comby[i,names(train[[i]])] <- train[[i]]
}
```

I tried using `do.call(rbind, train)` but that doesn't work as it keeps adding new data into the old columns from the first iteration.

What's a better, faster way? I have around 1.5 million observations.
**Desired o/p** : the data frame should have all the columns. I want NA where there is no value. Also I am interested if it could be done faster without using any additional packages.

```
 Physics Chemistry PhysicalEducation English Mathematics serial ComputerScience Hindi Biology Economics Accountancy
1       8         7                 3       4           6 195490              NA    NA      NA        NA          NA
2       1         1                 1       3           3 190869              NA    NA      NA        NA          NA
3       1         2                 2       1           2   3111              NA    NA      NA        NA          NA
4       8         7                 6       7           7  47738              NA    NA      NA        NA          NA
5       1         1                 1       3           2  85520              NA    NA      NA        NA          NA
6       2         1                NA       4           8 182318              NA    NA       2        NA          NA
  BusinessStudies
1              NA
2              NA
3              NA
4              NA
5              NA
6              NA
```

Here is the reproducible code

```
train <- [{\"Physics\":8,\"Chemistry\":7,\"PhysicalEducation\":3,\"English\":4,\"Mathematics\":6,\"serial\":195490},{\"Physics\":1,\"Chemistry\":1,\"PhysicalEducation\":1,\"English\":3,\"Mathematics\":3,\"serial\":190869},{\"Physics\":1,\"Chemistry\":2,\"PhysicalEducation\":2,\"English\":1,\"Mathematics\":2,\"serial\":3111},{\"Physics\":8,\"Chemistry\":7,\"PhysicalEducation\":6,\"English\":7,\"Mathematics\":7,\"serial\":47738},{\"Physics\":1,\"Chemistry\":1,\"PhysicalEducation\":1,\"English\":3,\"Mathematics\":2,\"serial\":85520},{\"Physics\":2,\"Chemistry\":1,\"Biology\":2,\"English\":4,\"Mathematics\":8,\"serial\":182318},{\"Physics\":3,\"Chemistry\":4,\"PhysicalEducation\":5,\"English\":5,\"Mathematics\":8,\"serial\":77482},{\"Accountancy\":2,\"BusinessStudies\":5,\"Economics\":3,\"English\":6,\"Mathematics\":7,\"serial\":152940},{\"Physics\":5,\"Chemistry\":6,\"Biology\":7,\"English\":3,\"Mathematics\":8,\"serial\":132620}]
train <- rjson::fromJSON(train)
```

Comment: Would you please add a code to reproduce a sample, in order not start from it, instead of writing a new example?

Comment: Try `do.call(plyr::rbind.fill,lapply(train, data.frame))` or `dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(train, data.frame))`.

Comment: plz check my edited answer (sol.1) with purrr:map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point you can use purrr::map as follows:

A sample data set:

```
x <- list(list(physics=8,
               Chemistry=7,
               PhysicalEducation=3,
               English=4,
               serial=195490),
          list(physics=2,
               Chemistry=1,
               Biology=2,
               English=4,
               Mathematics=8,
               serial=182318))
```

**Sol.1** *[Shortest to avoid loops]*

```
zzz <- sapply(columns, function(n) map_dbl(x,n,.null=NA) ) %>% 
        data.frame()
```

Which gives:

```
> zzz
  Physics Chemistry PhysicalEducation English Mathematics serial ComputerScience Hindi Biology Economics
1      NA         7                 3       4          NA 195490              NA    NA      NA        NA
2      NA         1                NA       4           8 182318              NA    NA       2        NA
  Accountancy BusinessStudies
1          NA              NA
2          NA              NA
```

If you would like to understand how this works, you can check the longer solutions below.

**Sol.2** *[Manual assignment]*

-pick the values for each column:

```
z <- data.frame(
    serial = map_dbl(x,"serial",.null=NA),
    Biology = map_dbl(x,"Biology",.null=NA),
    Chemistry = map_dbl(x,"Chemistry",.null=NA)
        )
```

Which gives:

```
> z
  serial Biology Chemistry
1 195490      NA         7
2 182318       2         1
>
```

**Sol.3** *[Pre-defined dataframe and for-loop]*

- create a dataframe with a fixed size

  `zz <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(x), ncol = 12))`
- assign names

  `names(zz) <- columns`
- assign values from the lists

  `for(i in 1:ncol(zz)){
          zz[columns[i]] <- map_dbl(x,columns[i],.null=NA)
  }`

Which gives:

```
> zz
  Physics Chemistry PhysicalEducation English Mathematics serial ComputerScience Hindi Biology Economics
1      NA         7                 3       4          NA 195490              NA    NA      NA        NA
2      NA         1                NA       4           8 182318              NA    NA       2        NA
  Accountancy BusinessStudies
1          NA              NA
2          NA              NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in base R by combining `Reduce`, and `Map`.

**data**

Here is a dataset that matches your structure.

```
set.seed(1234)
temp <- replicate(7, setNames(replicate(7, sample(1:10, 1), simplify=FALSE), letters[1:7]),
                  simplify=FALSE)
```

To produce a data.frame from this, you can use

```
Reduce(rbind, Map(data.frame, temp))
  a b c  d e f  g
1 2 7 7  7 9 7  1
2 3 7 6  7 6 3 10
3 3 9 3  3 2 3  4
4 4 2 1  3 9 6 10
5 9 1 5  3 4 6  2
6 8 3 3 10 9 6  7
7 4 7 4  6 7 5  3
```

Where `data.frame` constructs data.frames with the inner elements. `Map` applies this to each element of the outer list, resulting in a list of data.frames. Finally, `Reduce` `rbind`s the data.frames in the list and produces a single data.frame.